# Django {% block %} explanation

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

I'm a Django beginner and I wanted to try and learn some of the Django-CMS basics.

When I started editing the default template that was generated by the installer, I noticed there are `{% block ... %}` blocks, but I couldn't find any documentation on what `block` means or more specific what `block title` and `block content` mean.

Both the Django and the Django-CMS documentation lacks of such an explanation, which is weird given the fact that this seems pretty basic. When I removed the `block title` block, the title got messed up.

I'm using:

- Django 1.8.15
- django-cms 3.4.1.

Comment: [Read this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/language/)

Comment: @dahrens Alright, I just read the it again and found what I missed. I guess I got confused because the django cms documentation says nothing about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `{% block %} ... stuff {% endblock %}` things you see are for making reusable HTML pieces (or partials, or blocks). In [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/), they use a subsystem called [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) (Jinja2).

Notice that the syntax you’ll see there is not exclusive to Jinja. The idea is that the programming language and framework uses a component to allow encapsulating HTML patterns. We call those [Web Templating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_template_system) and sometimes refer to them as "logic less". Even though we can loop and do conditionals.

In Jinja (and other similar syntax subsystems), `blocks` are parts we can then re-use. A "Macro" if you want. Jinja also has macros, where you can also add arguments to impact how the output will be generated.

Comment: Django's template language is separate from Jinjia. Although in recent versions you can *alternatively* use Jinja. But `block` is present in both.

Comment: Good call. I *did* not validate if it was separated code, or a reimplementation of the syntax.